# Exponential distribution: Finding the parameter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Please help me solve the following problem

> Time of production of one electronic component is given with
> exponential distribution with parameter **λ**. If the process lasts less than 3 hours, the component is working, otherwise it is defective. Events that component is working or that is defective have equally probability. Find:
>
> 1. Parameter  **λ**
> 2. Probability that the process will last less than 1 hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random variable that measures length of life, in hours. We are told that $X$ has density function $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ (for $x\gt 0)$.

We are also told that $\Pr(X\lt 3)=\Pr(X\ge 3)$. Each is therefore $\frac{1}{2}$.

But $\Pr(X\gt x)$, by integration, is equal to $e^{-\lambda x}$. It follows that
$$e^{-3\lambda}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Now we can solve for $\lambda$, by taking logarithm to the base $e$ of both sides.

And now that we have $\lambda$, we can find the probability the thing lasts less than $1$ hour, since $\Pr(X\le x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\gt 0$.

**Remarks:** $1.$ We were asked to find $\lambda$, so we did. But note that the second problem can be solved without finding $\lambda$ explicitly. For we had $e^{-3\lambda}=\frac{1}{2}$. Taking cube roots, we find that $e^{-\lambda}=2^{-1/3}$, and therefore $\Pr(X\lt 1)=1-2^{-1/3}$.

$2.$ The calculations of the problem  are closely related to **half-life** calculations that you have undoubtedly done several times in the past.  Individual atoms of a radioactive isotope have a lifetime that is exponentially distributed. The **median** lifetime is called the half-life of the substance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that we're actually told that $\Pr(X\lt 3)=\Pr(X\ge 3)=\frac{1}{2}$. Does this not mean that we should use $\Pr(X\lt 3)= \Pr(X\le 3) - \Pr(X = 3)$?

Comment: I have corrected my $\le$, but it does not change **anything**. Under a continuous distribution model, for any particular $a$, we have $\Pr(X=a)=0$. So for continuous distributions, one can afford to be casual about the distinction between $\le$ and $\lt$. It would take a while to give justification for $\Pr(X=a)=0$. You can think of it as saying that the area (integral) of the density function from $x=a$ all the way to $x=a$ is $0$.

Comment: Pr(X=3) = 0 because the random variable is continuous. So you will get the same result because Pr(X=3) doesn't change anything. Thanks @AndréNicolas for fast response.

Comment: Sure: I got that from what Andre said and revising the definition of p.d.f., which I haven't looked at for some time. @Andre Personally, I would've said we find $\lambda$ using the c.d.f. to find $\Pr(X\lt 3)=\Pr(X\le 3)=1-e^{3\lambda}=\Pr(X\ge 3)=\frac{1}{2}$ and so $e^{3\lambda}=\frac{1}{2}$. Why bother to integrate when the c.d.f. has been given to us on a plate?

Comment: That said, your reference to integration has clarified what the p.d.f. is for me. +1 Andre for the answer. +1 LeetzMKD for info on $Pr(X=3)$.